# javascript variable = x or y possible?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following javascript to get URL parameters...

```
function getUrlParams() {
  var params = {};
  window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
    params[key] = value;
  });
  return params;
}
var params = getUrlParams();
var urlvars = (params.email);
```

The URL has `?email=email@domain.com&fbemail=email@domain.com`

In most cases one of those values is blank, otherwise they're the same. So I'm trying to make   `urlvars = (params.email) or (params.fbemail)`

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why not literally `urlvars = params.email || params.fbemail`?

Comment: @kojiro Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @TJ. I did, apparently three or four minutes before your comment. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll go ahead and make my comment an answer. Why not literally write what you said?

```
urlvars = params.email || params.fbemail;
```

Comment: FYI, they are called [Short Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Created a simple fiddle try it here jsfiddle.net/atacJ for those who like to see it work

Comment: @Derek Short Circuit evaluation isn't the whole point though. What we're interested in here is the fact that an nonempty-string value for `params.email` and `params.fbemail` is *truthy*, but not *true*, so that when the boolean operation is complete the value remaining is not `true`, but some string. This would not work in PHP, for example, where `$foo = "" || "somestring"` will end up with the literal value `true`. (If you print it, you'll get `1`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
var urlvars = (params.email == "" ? params.fbemail : params.email);
```